# Oracle number OUT parameters are always 0

Tags: c#, oracle

I've a stored procedure that takes several input parameters and two number output parameters. If i execute the stored procedure from sql developer it prints the correct values of the two output parameters.

If i call the stored procedure from C#, the two output parameters **are always 0**.

Here i show the code:

```
    public int ExecuteStore(string storeToExecute, CountDocumentsData storeResultDataObject, int old_systemid, int current_systemid, params SearchFilter[] searchFilters)
    {
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(this.ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();
                objCmd.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();
                objCmd.CommandText = storeToExecute;
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                foreach (var filter in searchFilters)
                {
                    OracleDbType type = OracleDbType.Varchar2;

                    if (filter.GetType() == typeof(YearFilter) || filter.GetType() == typeof(MonthFilter)
                            || filter.GetType() == typeof(ApplicationFilter) || filter.GetType() == typeof(DocumentTypeFilter))
                    {
                        type = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
                        objCmd.Parameters.Add(filter.FilterName, type, 200).Value = filter.Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        type = OracleDbType.Int32;
                        objCmd.Parameters.Add(filter.FilterName, type).Value = filter.Value;
                    }                       
                }

                objCmd.Parameters.Add("Lower_SystemID", OracleDbType.Int32, 200).Value = old_systemid;
                objCmd.Parameters.Add("Higher_SystemID", OracleDbType.Int32, 200).Value = current_systemid;

                objCmd.Parameters.Add("DocumentsNumber", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                objCmd.Parameters.Add("DocumentsSize", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                int res = objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(objCmd.Parameters["DocumentsNumber"].Value.ToString()));
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(objCmd.Parameters["DocumentsSize"].Value.ToString()));

                return res;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Query error.", ex);
                throw new Exception("Error", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Stored procedure:

```
Procedure CountDocuments
(
    Application IN VARCHAR2, 

    YearDoc IN VARCHAR2,  

    MonthDoc IN VARCHAR2,

    UoId IN Integer,

    SearchOnSubjected IN Integer,

    DocType IN VARCHAR2,

    Lower_SystemID IN Integer,

    Higher_SystemID IN Integer,

    DocumentsNumber OUT Integer,

    DocumentsSize OUT Integer
  ) Is

  queryToExecute VarChar2 (2000);
  Begin

  queryToExecute := ...

  Execute Immediate queryToExecute 
             Into DocumentsNumber, DocumentsSize 
             Using YearDoc, MonthDoc, Lower_SystemID, Higher_SystemID;

  End CountDocuments;
```

Comment: show your procedure also ...

Comment: can you please provide what is here  `Execute Immediate queryToExecute 
             Into DocumentsNumber, DocumentsSize 
             Using YearDoc, MonthDoc, Lower_SystemID, Higher_SystemID;`

Comment: what is value of this part : queryToExecute := ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to use dynamic parameters, yet you bind them by position. That seems very strange. I do not know if what is in your `searchFilters` at runtime matches your stored procedure exactly, but if not you need to use

```
objCmd.BindByName = true;
```

or your parameters will end up in the wrong spots.